# Minimizing deep holes in sphere packings

Tags: discrete-geometry, sphere-packing

What's the current state of knowledge regarding packings of spheres in $n$-space that minimize the supremum of the sizes of the holes? This notion of tightness is more rigid than asymptotic density. I would expect tightest packings to coincide with densest periodic packings in low dimensions but not when $n$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: Are you asking about the packing-covering problem (see e.g. arXiv:math/0412320)?

Comment: Exactly! This answers my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are asking about is sometimes known as the packing-covering problem, since it asks for a configuration with a fixed packing radius that minimizes the covering radius, irrespective of mean density. The lattice version of the problem is solved in some dimensions (see Table 3 of [arXiv:math/0412320](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412320)), and indeed the answer is different than the optimal packing lattice in dimensions $d>2$ and from the optimal covering lattice in dimensions $d>3$. A surprisingly open problem according to the paper linked is whether in some dimension, the optimal packing-covering lattice has a ratio greater or equal to 2 between the covering radius and the packing radius. That would mean that no lattice packing in that dimension can be saturated, since there must be a hole where another translate of the lattice can fit.